# if we place the code at the top of view.phtml, code is working but not working at bottom

Tags: magento-1.9, product-view

When we insert the code after 2 lines at .phtml file, feature is working.

if we place anywhere after 2 lines in view.phtml file, its not working.

please look at the code & help me.

I inserted this following code in view.phtml :

```
<?php $end_datetime=$_product->getEcomdevExpiryDate(); 

$date =  date( "Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($end_datetime));   

$endstr= date(strtotime($date));
$nowstr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());

$now =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $nowstr); ?>

<span id="countdown" class"countdown">
<script>showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>')</script>
</span>
```

**view.phtml**

```
 <?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<!-- code-->

<?php $end_datetime=$_product->getEcomdevExpiryDate(); 

$date =  date( "Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($end_datetime));   

$endstr= date(strtotime($date));
$nowstr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());

$now =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $nowstr); ?>

<span id="countdown" class"countdown">
<script>showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>')</script>
</span>

<!-- code end -->

<?php $myattribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')->load($_product->getAttributeSetId())->getAttributeSetName();

if($myattribute =="Tshirts"){?>
            <div class="tshirt">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
                </script>
                <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
                <div class="product-essential">
                    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                        <div class="no-display">
                            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                        </div>

                        <div class="product-img-box">
                            <div class="product-name">
                                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                            </div>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="product-shop">
                            <div class="product-name">
                                <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                            </div>


                            <!-- Price -->

                            <div class="price-info">
                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

                            </div>
                            <?php $_price = $_product->getPrice();
                            $_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
                            if($_price > $_finalPrice){?>
                            <div class="save-me">

                                    <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
                                    <?php 
                                    $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
                                    $_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
                                    ?>

                                     <?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%<br/>
                                     <span>OFF</span>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php }?>


                            <!-- Price -->

                            <!-- Wishlist -->

                           <!--  <div class="wishlist">
                            <?php $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($_product->getId(),'product_id');
                              if($wishlist->getId()){?>
                                <span><?php echo $this->__('You are My Wishlist') ?> </span>                                                    

                            <?php }
                              else{?>
                                 <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $this->__('Save to Wishlist') ?>
                                </a>
                            <?php }?>

                            </div> -->

                            <!-- Wishlist -->

                            <!--<div class="extra-info">
                                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                            </div>-->

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>


                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                            <?php endif;?>

                            <!-- <div style="clear:both"></div> -->





                            <!-- check delivery -->                
                                <?php
                                //  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();
                                    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('check')->toHtml();

                                    ?>


                            <!-- check delivery end-->




                        </div>



                        <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                                <div class="add-to-box">
                                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                            <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                    <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <div class="add-to-box">
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <div class="dinfo"> 
                                <?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('delivery_info');?>
                            </div>

                        </div>




                        <div style="clear:both"></div>



                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

                        <div class="clearer"></div>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                        <?php endif;?>
                    </form>







                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    //<![CDATA[
                        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
                        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
                            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                                var form = this.form;
                                var oldUrl = form.action;

                                if (url) {
                                   form.action = url;
                                }
                                var e = null;
                                try {
                                    this.form.submit();
                                } catch (e) {
                                }
                                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                                if (e) {
                                    throw e;
                                }

                                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                                    button.disabled = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

                        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
                            if(this.validator) {
                                var nv = Validation.methods;
                                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                                // Remove custom datetime validators
                                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                                    }
                                }

                                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                                    if (url) {
                                        this.form.action = url;
                                    }
                                    this.form.submit();
                                }
                                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                            }
                        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
                    //]]>
                    </script>
                </div>

                <div class="extra-attributes">

                        <div class="fit">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo "Fit Details"; ?></div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="fabric">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo "Fabric Details"; ?></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="desc">
                            <div class="title"><?php echo "Description"; ?></div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="info"><?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('fit_details');?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="info"><?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('fabric_details');?></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="info"><?php echo $_product->getDescription();?></div>
                            </div>

                        <div style="clear:both;display:none"></div>

                </div>

                <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
                    <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                            <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                                <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                                <dd class="tab-container">
                                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                                </dd>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        </dl>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

            </div>



            </div>
<?php }

else{?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
                </script>
                <div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
                <div class="product-view">
                    <div class="product-essential">
                        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product, array('_secure' => $this->_isSecure())) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
                            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                            <div class="no-display">
                                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="product-img-box">
                                <div class="product-name">
                                    <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                                </div>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                            </div>

                            <div class="product-shop">
                                <div class="product-name">
                                    <span class="h1"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></span>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <img src="<?php //echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/product_view_line.png') ?>"/> -->

                                <!-- Short Description -->

                                <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                                    <div class="short-description">
                                        <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif;?>

                                <!-- Short Description -->

                                <!-- Price -->

                                <div class="price-info">
                                    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product); ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

                                </div>
                                <?php $_price = $_product->getPrice();
                                $_finalPrice =$_product->getFinalPrice(); 
                                if($_price > $_finalPrice){?>
                                <div class="save-me">

                                        <?php if($_finalPrice < $_price): ?>
                                        <?php 
                                        $_savePercent = 100 - round(($_finalPrice / $_price) * 100); 
                                        $_saveAmount = number_format(($_price - $_finalPrice), 2);  
                                        ?>

                                         <?php echo $_savePercent; ?>%<br/>
                                         <span>OFF</span>

                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                                <?php }?>


                                <!-- Price -->



                                <!-- Wishlist -->

                               <!--  <div class="wishlist">
                                <?php $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/item')->load($_product->getId(),'product_id');
                                  if($wishlist->getId()){?>
                                    <span><?php echo $this->__('You are My Wishlist') ?> </span>                                                    

                                <?php }
                                  else{?>
                                     <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $this->__('Save to Wishlist') ?>
                                    </a>
                                <?php }?>

                                </div> -->

                                <!-- Wishlist -->

                                <!--<div class="extra-info">
                                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'default', false)?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_availability'); ?>
                                </div>-->

                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>






                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>

                                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                                <?php endif;?>

                                <!-- check delivery -->                
                                <?php
                                //  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();
                                    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('check')->toHtml();
                                    ?>


                            <!-- check delivery end-->

                            </div>

                            <div class="add-to-cart-wrapper">
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>

                                <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                                    <div class="add-to-box">
                                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                                            <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                                                <span class="or"><?php echo $this->__('OR') ?></span>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                        <?php //echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
                                <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                    <div class="add-to-box">
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sharing') ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <div class="dinfo"> 
                                    <?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('delivery_info');?>
                                </div>
                                <!-- <div class="ddescription">
                                    <h1>Product Description </h1>
                                    <?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>
                                </div> -->

                            </div>

                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('related_products') ?>

                            <div class="clearer"></div>
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
                            <?php endif;?>
                        </form>



                    </div>

                    <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
                        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
                            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                                    <dd class="tab-container">
                                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                                    </dd>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </dl>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

                </div>

                            <div class="next-content-product">
                                <h1>Product Description </h1>
                                <?php echo $_product->getDescription();?>

                                 <div class="size-space">
                                    <h1>Product Size & Space </h1>
                                    <?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('size_space');?>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                            <div class="next-level-content-product">


                                 <div class="interior-exterior">
                                    <?php echo $attribute_value = $_product->getData('interior_exterior');?>
                                </div>


                            </div>           

 <?php }?>
```

i want to place the code in middle of view.phtml file , because i need the feature in middle of Product view page.

Comment: did you checked in which condition it is coming ? if($myattribute =="Tshirts") or in else ?

Comment: @AkhileshPatel there is no attribute or attribute set related to "tshirt" exists in backend.

Comment: Try to add your code in if and else both places in view.phtml file.

Comment: insert your code before `<!-- check delivery end-->` line at both the places

Comment: @AnilSuthar i added like this : http://pasted.co/a6de367f, but it didt worked for me :

Comment: sorry guys you all are right , i forget to add in both condition.

Comment: @AkhileshPatel please post your comment as answer, as you gave the hint first.

Comment: no worries man!! take it as a hint :)

Comment: @AkhileshPatel it shows your greatness :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your view.phtml, in , a = is missing here

```
<span id="countdown" class"countdown">
```

Then, did you try to write a new  after

```
    <!-- check delivery end-->
</div>
```

Like this :

```
<div>
    <!-- code -->
    <?php 
        $end_datetime=$_product->getEcomdevExpiryDate(); 
        $date =  date( "Y/m/d H:i:s",strtotime($end_datetime));   
        $endstr= date(strtotime($date));
        $nowstr = Mage::getModel('core/date')->timestamp(time());
        $now =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s', $nowstr); 
    ?>
    <span id="countdown" class"countdown">
        <script>
            showtiming('<?php echo $date?>','<?php echo $now ?>');
        </script>
    </span>
    <!-- code end -->
```

Comment: i added like this : http://pasted.co/a320d1a8 , but it didt worked for me

Comment: Thanks, i found solution. i forget to add in both condition.